# How do I format a dynamic array for JSON encoding?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSON object for latitude and longitude coords (Google Maps). I am wanting the format to appear like this:

```
{"restaurants":[
{"lat":-84.9834,"lng":85.8374},
{"lat":-84.8378,"lng":85.8374},
{"lat":-84.7384,"lng":85.3784}
]  
}
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
try{

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dining','root','mypasswordhere');

}catch(PDOException $e){

   die($e);

}

$qry = "SELECT dining_lat, dining_long FROM dining_listings";
$getData = $conn->query($qry);
$latlngs = array();

while($row = $getData->fetchObject()){
   $myObj->lat = $row->dining_lat;
   $myObj->lng = $row->dining_long;
   $latlngs[] = json_encode($myObj);
}



?>
```

Comment: Okay, and so what's the output/result of your code? How does it differ from what you want? What debugging have you done?

Comment: The result is an array of JSON objects, but I am wanting to place that array of JSON objects within another JSON object like above.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: Me? No. Although, I may be approaching thos wrong to begin with. Google Maps provides a tutorial for dynamic maps with php/mysql, however ot uses XML and seems to be outdated (for example, uses mysql extensions instead of mysqli). I am wanting to create dynamic maps with multiple markers using data from mysql. I cannot find a good tutorial anywhere that uses JSON instead of XML.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to encode in the loop, just create an array of objects and then encode.  You can alias in the query to get the properties renamed:

```
$qry = "SELECT dining_lat AS lat, dining_long AS lng FROM dining_listings";
```

Then:

```
while($latlngs['restaurants'][] = $getData->fetchObject()){ }   
$latlngs = json_encode($latlngs);
```

Or to use the existing query:

```
while($row = $getData->fetchObject()){
   $latlngs['restaurants'][] = array('lat' => $row->dining_lat,
                                     'lng' => $row->dining_long);
}
$latlngs = json_encode($latlngs);
```

Or without the loop (need to alias in the query):

```
$qry = "SELECT dining_lat AS lat, dining_long AS lng FROM dining_listings";
```

Then:

```
$latlngs['restaurants'] = $getData->fetchAll();
$latlngs = json_encode($latlngs);
```

Comment: Wow really... sure take my answer np

Answer (score 0):

I would not waste your time looping if you are getting exactly what you need just use [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Below is what I believe should work:

```
<?php
    //Other stuff

    //$results should be an array of what you want now.
    $results = $getData->fetchAll();

    //If you really want the root "restaurants"
    $json = json_encode(["restaurants" => $results]);

?>
```